# Merge all MKMapRects to single MKPolygon

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmaprect

[image]I want to draw **corridor** using MKPolygon over MKMap using Mapkit. I have one route from station A to B.

I have MKMapRects around route for drawing corridor. Now i want to merge all rectangles in single Polygon and that is my Corridor along with route. **How to join all the rectangles in single Polygon .**

**No.of rectangles : 160**

Here i am attaching sample image indicating what i needed.

Here is code snippet.

```
for(int i=0;i<[self.boundingRectsArr count];i++) {

            lat1 = [[[self.boundingRectsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"xLT"] doubleValue];
    long1 = [[[self.boundingRectsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"yLT"] doubleValue];

    lat2 = [[[self.boundingRectsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"xRT"] doubleValue];
    long2 = [[[self.boundingRectsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"yRT"] doubleValue];
            lat3 = [[[self.boundingRectsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"xRB"] doubleValue];
    long3 = [[[self.boundingRectsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"yRB"] doubleValue];
    lat4 = [[[self.boundingRectsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"xLB"] doubleValue];
    long4 = [[[self.boundingRectsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"yLB"] doubleValue];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D rect[5];
            rect[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat1, long1);
    rect[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat2, long2);
    rect[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat3, long3);
    rect[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat4, long4);
            rect[4] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat1, long1);

    MKPolygon* polyCorridor = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:rect count:5];
    polyCorridor.title = @"Colorado";
    [self.map addOverlay:polyCorridor]; 
}
```

Thanks in Advance. Welcome to your answers.

Regards, Sagar P.[image]

Comment: Are there any assumptions that we can make?  Are all the rectangles the same size?  Are they squares?  Do you have the rectangles available, sorted, in order along the path?

Comment: It would also be easiest to give you a solution with actual **code** if you could show us what kind of data structure you have as an **input** to this algorithm?  For example, is it a `NSArray` of `MKMapRect`, ordered along the route?  Also, are you 100% sure that what you want is a `MKPolygon`?  Or are you just trying to draw a route on a map?  Would it be better if the sides were smoothed (which `MKPolygon` doesn't give you)?

Comment: @Nate : Yes I have all MKMapRect Array in sorted Order as route. Let me attach   final OutPut what i want actully and How its looks like.

Comment: @Nate : I have attached final Image, Please have a look its look like tube around the route (corridor around route) with perticular distance. suppose its 10 KM.

Comment: So, it sounds like you want a final corridor where the width of the corridor is the same, for the whole route?  Is that correct?  I'm just curious.  How is it that you **start** with an array of **rectangles**?  Normally, I would assume that someone would start with an array of points, so I'm curious what exactly one rectangle represents.

Comment: Finally, I just want to make sure that you want a true corridor, where the width is an actual *distance* (for example, 1 km).  That means that as the map zooms out, the corridor will *look* thinner, not stay the same visual width.

Comment: let me tell you what corridor represents you. i have two contacts like A and B. i have drawn route from set of points. now i have all contacts in my Database.I am specifying distance suppose 8 Km. I have to draw corridor along with route of 8 Km distance and display all reachable objects along with route.

Comment: What do you mean by *reachable*?  Reachable by driving?  Is the 8km in your example the *length* of the route (distance from Point A to Point B, along the route), or the *width* of the corridor (thickness of the tube)?

Comment: thickness of tube is 8 KM, forget reachable objects.

Comment: @Nate : still any confusion ?

Answer (score 0):

So, to be fast:

- **Draw corrigor**: draw second thick line.
- **Highlight objects in corridor**: calculate them without a polygon union, but with distance-to-route approach.

You could draw two lines in your overlay implementation, one, thin, for route, and one for a corridor - thiiick and semi-transparent, you could try to calculate point to km ratio using data MKMapView provides and calculate the thick line width. And for the objects on map you want to highlight - you could use different approaches, there are number of algos for finding points near curve or a straight line. You even could be rather straightforward: split the route into straight lines and check the distance of all the objects - that would be very slow, but it will work (sure you'll need to google for those complex algos for that).

Answer (score 0):

Simple, first convert the MKMapRects to MKPolygons, then create the union of all the MKPolygons using this library:
https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/MKPolygon-GPC unfortunately its not free.